# Stick Android ListView "categories" to top

Tags: android, listview, scroll, contacts

Im working on an application where I load items from a webservice and display them in a list using ListView. I was wondering if I could have certain "titles" between some of them, and when you scroll through them, they stick to the top of the list, until another "title" comes and takes the spot. An example of this is the Android contacts application:

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1440/contactss.png

NOTE: Since I can't post images yet, I posted the direct link

The letters G, H and J.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching on Google I found a nice code of ListView with sticking categories, also includes a working sample project:

http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Answer (score 8):

The good thing about Android is you can always look at the [application source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=tree;hb=HEAD). It uses a [PinnedHeaderListView](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/PinnedHeaderListView.java;h=9d1391b2b9c50a2c4f8d2f581b26c59b69e83293;hb=HEAD) to implement the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've just used this project, it works https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems